# Convert Custom JSON Object to a VB.NET Object

Tags: .net, vb.net, json, visual-studio-2010, json.net

I have a JSON object that looks like this.

```
{
 "Errors":{
   "err1":[
     //* Array of err1 objects
   ],
   "err2":[
     //* Array of err2 objects
   ]
 }
}
```

I use this object to report errors found on a request to a PHP page.

I want to convert that object to a vb.Net object declared basically like this:

```
Public Class WebErrContainer
  Public Errors as List(Of IWebError)
End Class

Public Class Err1
  Implements IWebError
End Class

Public Class Err2
  Implements IWebError
End Class

Public Interface IWebError
End Interface
```

I don't know if my implementation is good enough, i'm relatively new to vb.net so my skills in OOP are a little low right now.

That's it... i think i've explained the situation as well as i could.

If you need more information, i will give it .

Thanks in advance for any help that you could give. Thanks.

PD: I'm currently using Newtonsoft's JSON.Net library. Feel free to recommend some other library or method to deal with JSON in VB.NET.

---

I solved the situation by doing this:

```
Public Sub New(ByVal jsonText As String)
    Dim jObject As JObject = jObject.Parse(jsonText )
    Dim jErrors As JToken = jObject("Errors")
    Dim jS = New JsonSerializer()

    ' This is the "temporal" dictionary that stores the errors like they are 
    ' stored in JSON
    Dim jsErrs As New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of Object))

    ' List that is going to be passed to the "Errors" field in the class
    Dim lErrors As New List(Of IWebError)



    jsErrs = jS.Deserialize(New JTokenReader(jErrors ), jsErrs .GetType)
    If Not jsErrs Is Nothing Then
        For Each errType As KeyValuePair(Of String, List(Of Object)) In jsErrs 
            For Each Err As Object In errType.Value
                lErrors .Add(jS.Deserialize(New JTokenReader(Err), Type.GetType(errType.Key)))
            Next
        Next
    End If
    Me.Errors = lErrors
End Sub
```

Comment: I added a solution i came out with... Please feel free to report any errors found in the code.

Thanks for the answers svick and Jayesh...

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest solution is to make `Errors` into a read-only property that is computed based on `Err1` and `Err2`:

```
Public Class WebErrContainer
  Public Readonly Property Errors as List(Of IWebError)
    Get
      Return (Ctype(Err1, IEnumerable(Of IWebError))).Concat(Err2).ToList
    End Get
  End Property

  Public Err1 as List(Of Err1)
  Public Err2 as List(Of Err2)
End Class
```

Comment: I have not only that two types of errors, this solution did'nt helped me, i posted a solution on the main post.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just use Deserialize to do it automatically for you, or is there something strange going on.  I've used Newtsonsoft, and I did it like this (in c#)

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of MyJsonFromPHP)(jsonResponseText)

Public Class MyJsonFromPHP
     Public Property Errors as ErrorCollection
End Class

Public Class ErrorCollection
    Public Property err1 As List(Of Err1)
    Public Property err2 As List(Of Err2)
End Class

Public Class Err1
    Public Property code as Integer
    Public Property message as String
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this may help you .
here strJSON is your JSON String

```
Dim jsS As New JavaScriptSerializer : objPostData = jsS.DeserializeObject(strJSON)
```

After that you can iterate like this

```
For Each objTop As Object In objPostData
                objDic = CType(objTop, Generic.Dictionary(Of String, Object))
                dim strError  as string = objDic.Item("Errors")
Next
```

Let me know if anything else you want